# why won't this mysql line run with my php?

Tags: php, mysql

basically what I am trying to do is run a sql statement that inserts select parts of the query results into a table that was recently created. I tested it with mysql and ran this line

```
INSERT INTO searched(imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, `like`, dislike) 
SELECT imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, `like`, dislike
FROM boardgamelist
WHERE gamename LIKE '%david%'
```

that successfully ran 
but when I put the same line into the php from what I was given from phpmyadmin the mysql_query doesn't seem to run

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO searched(imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory,
`like`,   dislike) \n"
. "SELECT imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, `like`, dislike\n"
. "FROM boardgamelist\n"
. "WHERE gamename LIKE \'%david%\'";
    //copies query
    $copy_query = mysql_query($sql);
```

previously in my code however i do have a mysql command (confirmed to work) that creates the table "searched" 
what am I forgetting to do with the mysql command that doesn't allow it to run?

Comment: Get rid of all those unnecessary concatenations and `\n`.  You don't need to escape the single quotes around `%david%` with backslashes.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem or not, but I noticed you have escape characters on the ' near 'david' but not near 'like'.

Comment: The entire bare SQL string you have at the top can become a double-quoted PHP string without ANY special escaping or concatenating in linebreaks.

Comment: And if it fails, what does `mysql_error()` tell you?

Comment: thank you michael and kditraglia, esp michael. if you can answer that as an answer as opposed to a question I can give you the right answer mark bro. it works perfectly just as it should.

Comment: Do you come from a Java background, out of curiosity?  PHP supports multi-line strings just fine, and in fact it has [syntax that is specifically designed for multi-line strings](http://php.net/heredoc).

Comment: honestly I have a .net background more than anything. I got the line of code from php myadmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten spaces at your line breaks:

```
. "SELECT imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, `like`, dislike\n"
                                                                   ^---here
. "FROM boardgamelist\n"
                     ^---here
```

That'd make the final query string be:

```
... dislikeFROM boargamelistWHERE
```

If you had even bare bones error handling, e.g.

```
$copy_query = mysql_query($sql) or die(msyql_error());
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you'd have been informed of the syntax errors.

Comment: thats very blunt bro, but exactly what I needed in an answer. now I understand why my program didn't work, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO searched(imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, `like`, dislike) "
. "SELECT imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, `like`, dislike "
. "FROM boardgamelist WHERE gamename LIKE '%david%'";
```

Comment: You need a space between `dislike` and `FROM`

Comment: yea just mentioned it myself ;)